# Creating a bracket [] macro for \ref when using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, labels, brackets, ref

I've been trying to add brackets around cross-references in a more automatic manner in my recent report, but haven't been able to do so just yet. A simple `\newcommand`-macro does not seem to work. I've tried the `\eqref{fig:label}` from the `amsmath` package, but I want brackets '[#1]' and not paranthesis '(#1)'.
Another solution was trying `\let\oldref\ref` followed by `\AtBeginDocument\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{[\oldref{#1}]}` to combat `hyperref` controlling the `\ref` command, but this did not seem to work.

My question is, is there a way to create a macro with brackets around `\ref` (or a similar command that does this) instead of writing `[\ref{fig:label}]` everytime?

I am a relatively new user, so pardon any inconveniences.

Comment: You should probably be a bit more explicit about what it is you are going to use this for. To me, having `Theorem~\ref{key}` returning `Theorem~[2.3]` looks very strange.

Comment: What is the problem with hyperref redefining \ref? You want to remove the link? Cleveref might be useful, lots of customisation possible